# I want to be prompted for my BitLocker password straight after login

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, bitlocker

I'm on Windows 10. BitLocker is password-protected, no TPM, and is encrypting my data drive, but not my system drive. I did have it on my system drive, but the emergency-boot Windows Recovery never properly unlocked the C drive, so if I needed to restore a recovery point, I had to decrypt the system drive first. After this had happened a couple of times, I decided just to keep the system drive decrypted.

When the system drive was encrypted, I'd just enter the system-drive password at power-on, and it would unlock both system and data drives.

However, now, if I want to unlock the data drive, I have to open Explorer, click on the drive, and then it opens a popup window for me to enter my BitLocker password:

[image]

My standard user login is not an admin. I know I could get a prompt to unlock the drive with an admin-level script, but I don't want to have to enter my admin password *and* my BitLocker password each time. And besides, the system obviously has a way to prompt a normal user for the password.

So I guess some sort of macro recorder that opened the explorer window, and clicked on the encrypted drive, would do it. But isn't there a simpler, saner way to get this window to pop up, that I could put in to run after login?

It doesn't absolutely need to be that dialogue box, but I'd rather that than a command-line window.

Comment: I presume a file explorer shortcut opening a folder doesn't work?

Comment: You could also try [`manage-bde`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829854(v=ws.11).aspx). While both are capable to be called from the command line you should have a look whenever the dialogs themselves appeal to you. The prompts aren't necessarily command line prompts.

Comment: Have you considered adding a shortcut to the root directory of the drive to one of the startup applications groups? It would open an Explorer window (which could be set to open minimized), but it should trigger a password prompt in the process.

Answer (score 7):

As the admin user, I created a new shortcut `D:\` in file `D.lnk` in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\` folder. NB this is not a shortcut to `explorer D:\`, but just bare `D:\`. Admin permission was only needed once, to create the shortcut - it's not needed when executing it.

Now, whenever any user logs in, they get the dialogue box shown in the question, if the drive is not yet unlocked.

And it does not open an Explorer window, if the password was needed. If, however, the drive was already unlocked at login, an explorer window does appear.

Comment: Is there a way to have the prompt even before (pre-boot)? Because with this method every program from D:\ that should start on boot cannot be started because we would need to enter the password in 0.1 ms ;) to allow the next programs to have acccess to D:\